# PHP condition check fail

Tags: php

Trying to iterate through a list to find a particular element but to no avail.

**check.php**

```
<?php

$username = (isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : null);
$john = "John";

$fileName = "users.txt"; // get the text file

$users = file_get_contents( $fileName ); // text file to string
$objUsers = json_decode( $users ); // string to object

// iterate through the list and find John
for( $i = 0; $i < count($objUsers); $i++ ){

    if(// what to do here?){
        echo '<div>John is found</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div>John is NOT found</div>';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

as an OOP person, I'd find it logical to have the condition like

```
if( $objUsers[$i] == $john)
```

but it seems this approach fails in php as it always yields to "John is NOT found" even though John does exist in the list. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: What values are in `$objUsers`?  You claim the value `"John"` is there, how have you confirmed this?  (PHP can, in fact, successfully compare two strings.)

Comment: use `var_dump($objUsers[$i]);` to see what's inside.

Comment: Show your structure of $objUsers. Using a foreach instead of a for loop might be easier.

Comment: `if($objUsers[$i]->name == 'John'` or something very similar to that as your JSON should have key/value pairs.

Comment: You could try `$objUsers = json_decode( $users, true );` to make sure $objUsers is an array, associative or not. Otherwise, it could be an stdClass.

Comment: David, castis, aynber, thanks for the suggestions, var_dump confirmed that the file contains John.

Comment: Jay Blanchard, thanks, I think this is the right path, tried it and it returned as "John is found", removed it from the text file and the result now is "John is NOT found". thank you!