# PHP condition check and AJAX calling issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

got some kind help here recently so I thought I'd ask couple more questions, 2 to be exact.

**Problem 1.**

This is related to one of my previous questions can be found here: [PHP condition check fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841376/php-condition-check-fail)

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$username = (isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : null);

$fileName = "users.txt";

$users = file_get_contents( $fileName );
$objUsers = json_decode( $users );

// iterate through the list and find John
for( $i = 0; $i < count($objUsers); $i++ ){

    if($objUsers[$i]->username == $username){
        echo '<div>John is found</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div>John is NOT found</div>';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

The trouble is now it always and everytime returns "John is found" even if I typed "Charles" into the username field as it iterates through the whole list and will eventually find "John", no matter what. The way I need to change the code is to return "John is found" only when "John" is typed into username field.
I think it is a relatively easy problem for those of you experts out there but my OOP experience is not very helpful with this syntax.

**Problem 2.**

I would like to trigger an ajax call after a click event has done some stuff.

Code:

```
$("#div1").click(function(){

    // if condition is true
    if (...){ // working
    // then if this condition is also true
    if (...){ // working
        var link = "do-some-stuff.php" // working
        $.notify("task is done"); // working
        $.getJSON( link, function( input ){});
        // how to refer to div2 or should i just paste the ajax function here?
        // tried this latter one, no success
    }

$("#div2").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: "other-suff.php",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data){
          $('#div3').html(data);
          }
       });
}
```

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: You have John hard-coded (`$objUsers[$i]->username == 'John'`), shouldn't you be using `$username` (`$objUsers[$i]->username == $username`)?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by __refer to div2__? Do you want to trigger a click on `div2`? or just make another ajax call after the `getJSON` call? Please be more specific :)

Comment: sorry, my bad, made some changes in the code I pasted here but obviously "John" is not hardcoded in the original one, so I use $objUsers[$i]->username == $username, no avail. referring to div2 I mean to call it, if you like. what I want to happen is to carry out the "do-some-stuff.php" and show a notification it is done. both happens, but I want the ajax call to be triggered. it does not happen.

Comment: You type "Charles". Is it in the txt? Then just change the text to `"<div>$username found.</div>"`

Comment: So you only want to check `users.txt` when 'John' is typed into the username field? It's hard to understand what you are looking for @Lale and you can't really __call__ `div2` but you can trigger a click on the `div2` element by using `$('#div2').trigger('click')`

Comment: Lelio Faieta the point is not to find Charles, Bobby or whoever but to find "John" only if "John" is typed. in all other cases, I want to see "John is NOT found", not the name of the user who was typed.

Comment: Mr. Meeseeks, clicking happens before var link = "do-some-stuff.php" // working
        $.notify("task is done"); // working
        $.getJSON( link, function( input ){});

Comment: I don't see any **clicking** in your code. You have only defined two click functions on `#div1` and `#div2`

Comment: Mr. Meeseeks yes, the div1 click should trigger it, but it only triggers var link = "do-some-stuff.php" // working $.notify("task is done"); // working $.getJSON( link, function( input ){}); and not the ajax call, I tried it, doesn't get carried out if I add it after the $getJSON part.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your problem 1:

```
<?php

$username = (isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : null);

$fileName = "users.txt";

$users = file_get_contents( $fileName );
$objUsers = json_decode( $users );

// iterate through the list and find John
for( $i = 0; $i < count($objUsers); $i++ ){

    if($username=='John'){
        if($objUsers[$i]->username == $username){
            echo '<div>John is found</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div>John is NOT found</div>';
            break;
        }
    }else{
        echo '<div>You are not looking for John</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

added an if to see if you tiped John -> look for John in the txt. Else alert that you didn't type John in the box

Comment: okay, it's getting there! got some error messages but I think this is the right direction. made some simplification though with if($username=='John' && $objUsers[$i]->username == $username). thank you!

Comment: with your simplification you miss some conditions but it's hard to understand what you really want to get. Please mark the answer as solved and open a new one for the other question

Comment: I can only ask a question in every other hour so if there's no solution until, I'll open up a new question. thanks

Comment: btw... it is a good habit for all the other who comes to this site to mark as solved the question that have a correct answer. I've seen you keep just asking skipping to do so. This is not how this site is intended to work